# How to Find even number

Tags: webmethods

I want Even number List of  a string in web methods development . If i give input string,i want Even number of that input string in web methods flow steps.

ex input number 10
   output number 2 4 6 8

Answer (score 0):

1. make a loop over a stringList
2. inside a loop call Java servis (build it yourself), that will check modulo of iteration number.
3. check modulo in a branch.